# Design Support TabLayout Style Not Applied

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

I'm working with android.support.design.widget.TabLayout and I'm having a REAL hardtime trying to make the applied theme to work. Here's the XML I'm trying to use:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerLayout_tabView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TabLayout.Theme"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerLayout_viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the style that is being applied:

```
<style name="TabLayout.Theme" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/rowHeaderColor</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">5dp</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Jacksonville.Tab</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">#000</item>
    </style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Jacksonville.Tab" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#4C4D4F</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

When applied to the theme, the TextColor doesn't appear as the one I selected. I thought it was a problem with my sight so I changed it to Selected: Black and not selected: white but the same colors appeared. Is there something I would be needing to besides that in order for the theme to be applied? The problem is only with the text colors. The textAllCaps, textSize and other attributes are being applied with no major problems.

Thanks!

Comment: None of the colors work, or perhaps @color/rowHeaderColor works but #000 and #4C4D4F fail? A long shot, but did you try defining these in the res/values/colors too?

Comment: #000 & #4C4D4F fail to work. rowHeaderColor does works. Yes, tried to define them on colors.xml and it didn't worked.